# rEFInd bootloader not loading by default

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, refind

I'm in the process of hacking my Surface Pro 3 with Ubuntu. The Surface is a UEFI x64 system that uses *Secure Boot*. At this point I have Ubuntu installed along side Windows, booting through GRUB2 with *Secure Boot* disabled. This is all fine and good, but I'd like to swap out GRUB for rEFInd, and if possible, re-enable *Secure Boot*.

1. Following the instructions on [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/secureboot.html#shim), I installed rEFInd from the binary ZIP using: `sudo bash install.sh --localkeys --shim shim.efi`, which completed successfully. (See install instructions [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#installsh).)
2. `efibootmgr -v` reports:

   ```
   BootCurrent: 0001
   Timeout: 2 seconds
   BootOrder: 0001
   Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(2,af800,64000,025ae8fc-da93-4531-b8b2-519ff2ec37ee)File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
   Boot0001* rEFInd Boot Manager   HD(2,af800,64000,025ae8fc-da93-4531-b8b2-519ff2ec37ee)File(\EFI\refind\shim.efi)
   Boot0002  USB Drive ACPI(a0341d0,0)PCI(14,0)USB(1,0)HD(1,20,1dda7e0,0000aa76)..BO
   ```
3. And my `/boot/efi/EFI` folder looks like:

   ```
   Boot/
     bootx64.efi
   Microsoft/
     Boot/
       bootmgfw.efi
       bootmgr.efi
   refind/
     grubx64.efi (<-- This is actually rEFInd)
     MokManager.efi
     shim.efi
   ubuntu/
     grubx64.efi
     MokManager.efi
     shimx64.efi
   ```

**My issue is when I reboot, it dumps me straight back into GRUB2. Why is it not loading rEFInd when everything looks good? How can I get it to load rEFInd?**

A behavior I've noticed in the past is that the firmware sometimes likes to ignore configuration, and go straight for `Boot/bootx64.efi` or `Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` directly. The Ubuntu installer's "Install Alongside Windows" option surprisingly managed to configure the GRUB2 bootloader correctly so that it actually loads GRUB2 without a problem. I'd like to replicate that same success, but with rEFInd instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have four suggestions, off the top of my head:

- **Try another Shim** -- I've found that some EFIs are a bit flaky about loading certain signed binaries, and will reject some signed binaries that other EFIs accept. Unfortunately, this quirk affects some copies of Shim, so you may just need to try another Shim binary. Using the one that's working for Ubuntu is a good starting point. If you swap out your Shim, be sure to replace the MokManager binary, too.
- **Use `bcdedit` in Windows** -- You might try using the `bcdedit` program in Windows to register rEFInd (or rEFInd's copy of Shim) as the boot loader. From an *Administrator* Command Prompt window, typing `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\refind\shim.efi` should do the job.
- **Customize your Secure Boot configuration** -- You could bypass Shim by replacing your computer's default Secure Boot keys with your own keys. This process is a bit tedious, but it gives you much better control of the process. See [my page on how to do this](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/controlling-sb.html) for details.
- **Copy rEFInd to `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi`** -- It's conceivable that your computer is booting this way already, although that seems unlikely. You can either copy the files manually or use the `mvrefind.sh` script that comes with rEFInd, although that script will *move,* rather than *copy,* the binaries. I strongly recommend backing up what's there already before you proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the exact same problem. I though that I found the solution [here](https://dev.to/hollowman6/a-solution-to-refind-unable-to-load-using-shim-when-secure-boot-is-enabled-1e8l), but even following all the steps with shim 15 instead of shim 15.3 and going through MOK manager and importing bootx64.efi the system will just go straight to grub, which is setup as the default bootloader bootx64.efi

I know my setup is correct because I can get to rEFInd if I disable secure boot.

Also using shim 15 did change the behaviour of the system.  With shim 15.4 I get an error saying that there is some security violation, but with shim 15 now rEFInd fails silently and I am back to bootx64.efi.  Another test I did is to replace the .efi in EFI/ubuntu with shim 15 and now ubuntu also fails to boot with Secure Boot turned on.

It is possible that something is being left behind either in my ESP or NVRAM and that is the cause of my problem.  I just don't know.

Update: I found another [solution](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/howto-enable-secure-boot-with-refind/121403/6), which seems to be specific to majaro, and involves quite a few steps.  But I just downloaded [shim-x64-15-2.x86_64.rpm](https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=1077877) and extracted

```
 2018-04-30  01:41 PM         1,210,776 shimx64.efi
```

copied the file to EFI/refind and rebooted.

To my amazement, it actually works!  The only small problem left for me is that shellx64.efi now stopped working.  I guess I'll need to put its signature into MOK.

2nd Update.  I've now tested the procedure on two more laptop and this is how I got it to work consistently:

1. Follow R.W. Smith's guide and use `sudo ./refind-install --shim /boot/efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi` so that Ubuntu 20's shimx64.efi and mmx64.efi will be copied into /boot/efi/refind
2. Reboot, and you should be presented with MOK management screen.  Enter your password so that key/refind.cer will be imported into MOK.
3. Now boot into Linux or Window and replace shimx64.efi with the 5.2 version downloaded from [here](https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=1077877)
4. Reboot and refind should work now.

I tried to do it by using the fedora shimx64 from the very beginning and using the mmx64.efi from fedora, but that result in the MOK management screen not coming up after reboot.  Maybe the combination of 5.2 shimx64 with the Ubuntu mmx64 will work but I've not tried that combination yet.